# How to use scala 2.10 trunk with sbt 0.11.0? (Unresolved dependencies)

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

What's the right way to use sbt with 2.10 trunk?  I tried the obvious:

```
james@James-Moores-iMac:~/workspace/Deleteme3$ cat build.sbt 
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

But that gives:

```
james@James-Moores-iMac:~/workspace/Deleteme3$ sbt compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/james/.sbt/plugins
[info] Set current project to default-ee38f7 (in build file:/Users/james/workspace/Deleteme3/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/james/workspace/Deleteme3/}default-ee38f7...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/james/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/scala-library-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/scala-library-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/Users/james/workspace/Deleteme3/}default-ee38f7/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 18, 2012 10:39:29 AM
james@James-Moores-iMac:~/workspace/Deleteme3$
```

Trying the suggestion of the new sbt launcher with -sbt-snapshot fails too:

```
james@James-Moores-iMac:/tmp/sfasdf$ sbt -sbt-snapshot compile
Detected sbt version 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT
Using /Users/james/.sbt/0.12.0-SNAPSHOT as sbt dir, -sbt-dir to override.
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jna
    confs: [default]
    1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (838kB/13ms)
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.0-20120319-052150 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    38 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (7712kB/159ms)
Getting Scala 2.9.1 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (19939kB/426ms)
[info] Set current project to wand (in build file:/private/tmp/sfasdf/)
Getting Scala 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT ...
downloading http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/scala-compiler-2.10.0-20120319.161232-290.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT!scala-compiler.jar (28525ms)
downloading http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/scala-library-2.10.0-20120319.161232-293.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT!scala-library.jar (16869ms)
downloading http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/jline-2.10.0-20120319.161232-290.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT!jline.jar (1674ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (21204kB/91ms)
[info] Updating {file:/private/tmp/sfasdf/}default-59a990...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/james/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-SNAPSHOT/scala-library-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/private/tmp/sfasdf/}default-59a990/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 54 s, completed Mar 20, 2012 7:37:55 AM
```

Comment: sbt 0.11.0 won’t work. Try paulp’s [sbt loader script](https://gist.github.com/2012631).

Comment: It would probably be better to link to the repository rather than some six-months-out-of-date gist of it.  https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt

Comment: Edited the question with the failure when using the new sbt launcher from @extempore's comment

Comment: What do people on Windows do?  That's a bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use trunk with SBT 0.11.0, and you'll never be able to do so. Newer SBT versions (snapshots of 0.12) can handle it.

Comment: This is technically correct because of the incompatible change to the compiler in 2.10, but he never got to that error.  I believe the immediate issue here is not adding the appropriate snapshots repository, which would still be a problem in 0.12.

Comment: It's a bit confusing that sbt -sbt-snapshot (which I think gets me a 0.12.? version of sbt)  is able to get the compiler, but then fails to get scala-library.  Or at least I think that's what the output is telling me.

Comment: The repository is `Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")`.  What implies it got the compiler?

Comment: I updated the question with a clean run - it looks like it's fetching the compiler (and the library too), and reporting [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-SNAPSHOT!scala-library.jar (16869ms).  That's why I assumed I didn't need a different repo.

Answer (score 4):

Use this version of the actual sbt script: https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt

Run with

```
sbt -sbt-snapshot
```

Add this to your build.sbt file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
```

(added as a new answer to combine a couple answers in one place - but marked Daniel's answer as correct.)