# How to change Scala version in SBT/Android Plugin/Project?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, scala-2.10, sbt-android-plugin

I'm using SBT v0.13 with jberkel/android-plugin, which I am trying to modify.

In order to do that, I need to work with [Scala 2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/distributions/scala-2.10.0-latest.zip) in my test project.

So far, I've used Scala 2.9.1, and I need to switch to 2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555 now, but I'm not so proficient with this stuff.

I've ran into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888031/changing-scala-version-in-existing-sbt-project), but that doesn't work for me.

I get the following output when I try to compile and push my test application to device:

```
[info] Wrote C:\Users\Administrator\myProject\target\scala-2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555\src_managed\main\scala\com\google\summer\TR.scala  
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/Administrator/myProject/}My Project...  
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555 ...  
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555  
[warn] ==== local: tried  
[warn]   C:\Users\Administrator\.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555/ivys/ivy.xml  
[warn] ==== public: tried  
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555/scala-library-2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555.pom  
[info] Resolving org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555;1.8.RC1 ...  
[warn]  module not found: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555;1.8.RC1  
[warn] ==== local: tried  
[warn]   C:\Users\Administrator\.ivy2/local/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555/1.8.RC1/ivys/ivy.xml  
[warn] ==== public: tried  
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555/1.8.RC1/scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555-1.8.RC1.pom  
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::  
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555: not found  
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555;1.8.RC1: not found  
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
[error] {file:/C:/Users/Administrator/myProject/}My Project/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555: not found  
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.0-20120710-144914-026a70d555;1.8.RC1: not found  
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 11.07.2012. 08:55:13
```

Comment: Anything in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760596/how-to-use-scala-2-10-trunk-with-sbt-0-11-0-unresolved-dependencies help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

> set scalaVersion := "2.10.0-SNAPSHOT"

It will automatically pick the latest published scala version.